# How to run multiple ingress gateway for public and private domains

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have multiple public and private applications running in my kubernetes cluster. I want to separate out traffic for each type by running multiple istio-gateway deployments. Is there any straight methods to implement it with istio.

For both type of application I am using custom CA and importing certificates as secret manually. Do I need to anything cert manager part to achieve my use case

Answer (score 2):

The cert-manager is not required to achieve this configuration.

To install custom istio-ingress-gateway (for you private domain) next to the default one (for public domain), you can take as an example '[example-values/values-istio-gateways.yaml](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/example-values)' values file (part of official Istio github project), and use it with helm, to generate all necessary manifest files to upgrade/extend your current Istio installation.

To generate manifest files use the following command:

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --set gateways.custom-gateway.namespace=nepomucen-custom -f install/kubernetes/istio-demo.yaml -f install/kubernetes/helm/istio/example-values/values-istio-gateways.yaml
```

Note: This creates custom gateway in non-default namespace

Comment: But the issue is i want to create two ingress gateway and if use helm, am i able to create two different ingress gateway in one release ?

Comment: Of course, this is exactly what helm will generate with the above command (default ingress gateway + custom ingress gateway in custom namespace). Try it yourself !

Comment: What i actually need is , in namespace A a ingressgateway a, and namespace B, a ingressgateway b, and a default ingressgateway in istio-system. I'm afraid the helm chart doesn't fit. what do you think ?

Comment: please refer to the sample custom-values file that can be used with '-f' flag to satisfy your requirement:
https://gist.github.com/nepomucen/a77b4aa8cb243d9c8943399c2ad0b514

Comment: beautiful. Thanks very much